# Help with adding CSS to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am really new to jquery and I dont really have time to see how it works (I work with PHP a lot) I want to make a jquery slideshow but I dont know how to add z-index to the images here: http://www.albavid.com/new/index.html

I can see that jquery adds some css elements like opacity, width.. etc. 
I tried to add a bigger z-index to the current image and lower z-index to the right images and left images.

Can anyone tell me how to add css with jquery so the current image(the biggest) to be on the top and then the others behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your javascript on the page with this:

I added in `$(el).css('z-index', 5)` and `$(el).css('z-index', 0)` in `currentCss`, `beforeCss`, and `afterCss`.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
    jQuery( '#flip' ).jcoverflip({
      current: 2,
      beforeCss: function( el, container, offset ){
        $(el).css('z-index', 0);
        return [
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 210 - 110*offset + 20*offset )+'px', bottom: '20px' }, { } ),
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: Math.max(10,200-10*offset*offset) + 'px' }, {} )
        ];
      },
      afterCss: function( el, container, offset ){
        $(el).css('z-index', 0);
        return [
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 + 110 + 110*offset )+'px', bottom: '10px' }, { } ),
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: Math.max(10,200-10*offset*offset) + 'px' }, {} )
        ];
      },
      currentCss: function( el, container ){
        $(el).css('z-index', 5);
        return [
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el, { left: ( container.width( )/2 - 200 )+'px', bottom: 0 }, { } ),
          $.jcoverflip.animationElement( el.find( 'img' ), { width: '400px' }, { } )
        ];
      },
      change: function(event, ui){
        jQuery('#scrollbar').slider('value', ui.to*25);
      }
    });


    jQuery('#scrollbar').slider({
      value: 50,
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        if(event.originalEvent) {
          var newVal = Math.round(ui.value/25);
          jQuery( '#flip' ).jcoverflip( 'current', newVal );
          jQuery('#scrollbar').slider('value', newVal*25);
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont know how to thank you! I will try to read the script and see what you have done.

I dont know what I can do for yoou cause you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

you can also get it working by using different classes the use [addclass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) - [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to toggle the effect works well if you're already familiar with CSS overrides

Comment: can you help me in details because I try to add z-index but whatever I do the script stops working! I might not be on the right track..

thanks for your time!

Comment: I upvoted the accepted answer as I think that's your best case to keep with the existing script, You can toggle the classes based on the width of the image and add the z-index the parent  - but ultimately that's like re-writing another little script

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the inline CSS by selecting the element and using the `css` method

Suppose an element has no z-index, or a different one, and you want to change it to 5

```
$("#elementId").css('z-index', 5);
```

Another option is to set up classes with certain CSS styles before hand and change the class of certain elements ie (currentShown, nextUp, etc)

Answer (score 0):

rather then waste your time reinventing the wheel why not just use a [jquery slideshow plugin](http://graphicalerts.com/20-best-jquery-slideshow-image-photo-gallery-plugins/)?

Comment: I have to do this for someone else, and he is a little bit picky :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `position` property of the elements to `relative`, otherwise they will be treated as `static` and ignore all settings to z-index.

Comment: a littel bit more detailed please,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `z-index` in question should be applied to the `<li>`, not the `<img>`.

---

Comment: how can I add it to the li? more info? because I have included the jquery files and the jquery script in the index but I dont know how it works, it looks like its like OOP and the class is initated in the index.html but I dont know I am really far from jquery. I am going to need some more help with the details.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the z-index of an element by using the .css() function.

```
$("#elem").css('z-index','1000');
```

However, two better options would be to either define CSS classes for the elements you want to style and toggle between them, or use some nice jQuery slideshow plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index'ing the `<li>` instead of the `<img>` is the right solution to fix the overlap. However, because the `<li>`s are dynamic and flip before and after each other, an applied `z-index` to all in a sequential order from left-to-right will not solve his issue.

Solving the issue will need a few more actions to invoke within jquery but not too much extra work. What needs to happen is for jQuery to apply a `z-index` **to the current `<li>`** higher than the rest of the batch for each event on the slider.

Since I don't have access to your code, you basically want to apply the following logic:
Whatever `<li>` is in front it should have a `z-index:1` and all other `<li>`s should have `z-index:0`. This should happen on every change in the slider.

@mcgrailm: Give him a break man, you can't learn how to swim unless you jump into the pool.

Comment: yeah I know, but for me now its the wrong time at the wrong place, thats why I cant jump to the pool! anyway.. thank you for your time